# Every principal $G$-bundle over a surface is trivial if $G$ is compact and simply connected: reference?

Tags: lie-groups, homotopy-theory, fiber-bundles, classifying-spaces

I'm looking for a reference for the following result:

> If $G$ is a compact and simply connected Lie group and $\Sigma$ is a compact orientable surface, then every principal $G$-bundle over $\Sigma$ is trivial.

The proof supposedly uses homotopy theory and classifying spaces. I'm not very familiar with either, so I don't know where to start looking.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The homotopy theoretic proof is as follows: Let $E \longrightarrow \Sigma$ be a principal $G$-bundle over a surface $\Sigma$. Such a bundle is determined by a homotopy class $[f_E] \in [\Sigma, BG]$ by classifying space theory. Since $G$ is simply connected (and presumably connected), the classifying space $BG$ is $2$-connected (*i.e.* connected, simply connected, and $\pi_2(BG) = 0$). A surface $\Sigma$ has the homotopy type of a $2$-dimensional CW-complex. Hence $[\Sigma, BG] = 0$ and it must be that $[f_E] = 0$, so that $E$ is the trivial bundle.

We have the following elementary fact in general:

> **Fact 1.** If $X$ is an $n$-dimensional CW complex and $Y$ is $n$-connected, then $[X, Y] = 0$.

Furthermore, a basic property of classifying spaces is the following:

> **Fact 2.** If $G$ is $(n-1)$-connected, then $BG$ is $n$-connected.

By the same argument as above, these two facts imply the following general fact:

> **Fact 3.** If $G$ is an $(n-1)$-connected Lie group and $X$ is an $n$-dimensional manifold, then every principal $G$-bundle over $X$ is trivial.

For example, every $\mathrm{SU}(2)$-bundle over a $3$-manifold is trivial.

---

I'll describe a few references here. First of all, if you want to know exactly how the classifying space $BG$ is constructed and that the principal $G$-bundle $EG \longrightarrow BG$ is universal, you can read sections 4.11-4.13 of Husemöller's *Fibre Bundles*. The main idea is the following:

> For a topological group $G$, there is a topological space $BG$ and a principal $G$-bundle $EG \longrightarrow BG$ with $EG$ contractible such that for any paracompact space $X$, isomorphism classes of principal $G$-bundles over $X$ are in one-to-one correspondence with homotopy classes of maps from $X$ to $BG$ as follows:
>   $$[X, BG] \leftrightarrow \text{Prin}_G(X),$$
>   $$[f] \leftrightarrow f^\ast EG.$$

Here $f^\ast EG$ is the pullback of $EG \longrightarrow BG$ by any map $f$ representing to homotopy class $[f] \in [X, BG]$. So to classify principal $G$-bundles over a paracompact space $X$ (*e.g.* a manifold), we can look at homotopy classes of maps from $X$ to $BG$. If we're lucky, some properties of $X$ and $BG$ can let us find $[X, BG]$ without doing much work.

I don't know of a place where Fact 1 appears as a theorem, but it is Exercise 117 in Davis and Kirk's [*Lecture Notes in Algebraic Topology*](http://www.indiana.edu/~lniat/book.pdf). You can solve by just working cell-by-cell.

Fact 2 follows from the long exact sequence of a fibration in homotopy and the fact that $EG$ is contractible. The long exact sequence of a fibration goes as follows: if $F \hookrightarrow E \to B$ is a fibration, then we have a long exact sequence
$$\cdots \to \pi_{k+1}(B) \to \pi_k(F) \to \pi_k(E) \to \pi_k(B) \to \pi_{k-1}(F) \to \cdots.$$
If we apply this to $G \hookrightarrow EG \to BG$ and use the fact that $EG$ is contractible, we find that $\pi_{k+1}(BG) \cong \pi_k(G)$, so if $G$ is $n$-connected, $BG$ is $(n+1)$-connected.

Finally, Fact 3 is just a corollary of Facts 1 and 2 as well as the basic properties of classifying spaces.

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that the "following general fact" isn't actually that much more general.  Every compact Lie group either has $\pi_1$ or $\pi_3$ nontrivial.  Further, every noncompact (connected?) Lie group deformation retracts onto its maximal compact subgroup, so the only noncompact 3-connected Lie groups are diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ and this then implies $BG$ is contractible, so $[X,BG] = \{\ast\}$.

Comment: I am familiar with the fundamental group and with singular and de Rham (co)homology. I can define the higher homotopy groups, but I cannot state any relevant "big theorems" by heart. I think I know what classifying spaces are about, meaning that in particular I more or less know the correspondence between homotopy classes of maps $\Sigma\to BG$ and $G$-bundles over $\Sigma$. I have never really worked with higher homotopy groups. (And I'm aware it may be hard to give a good answer to someone lacking this knowledge.)

Comment: @DaanMichiels: The main thing about classifying spaces to know is that the universal $G$-bundle $EG$ over $BG$ is contractible.  Then the long exact sequence in homotopy associated to the fibration $G \to EG \to BG$ tells you that $\pi_n(BG) = \pi_{n-1}(G)$.

Comment: @EricO.Korman - Thank you, that helps (though I have to think about it a little bit).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Any reference I can take a look at?